# In terms of doing self study, how can I practice my skills or knowledge in Software Testing?

Tags: learning

Are there free software tools where I can do mock testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's lots.  For starters, what software do you have on the machine that you're using right now?  Any reason to not try testing any of it?  You could always go grab a copy of some open source software.  Nightly releases are great for practice.  Is there any approach in particular that you're interested in?

Seeing that you say that you're looking for web testing, my own personal recommendation would be to install some sort of web debugger.  Since you're using mac, Fiddler is out of the question, however, it appears as though [CharlesProxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is an option.  It should help give you a good understanding of what's going on under the hood while you're browsing/interacting.

I'm not entirely certain about apple products, but, if you have a windows machine, you can use the [web platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to install applications locally to test on as well.

Furthermore, spending some time browsing some of the question/answers here, as well as places like [sqaforums](http://sqaforums.com) and [software testing club](http://softwaretestingclub.com) can give some great insight.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am working on a Mac and currently been playing with Wordpress. I guess I want to start learning how to test a web application. I would appreciate any tips you have. I haven't had any formal training in Software Testing but I've been doing some self study. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Keep an eye out for [Weekend Testing sessions](http://weekendtesting.com/) - a good way to learn testing and interact and learn from other testers

Comment: thanks a lot! I will learn a lot from this. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can look out for open source websites where you can work as a QA tester and you can apply different techniques to find bugs and then report them.